# Multiple filenames in Entity form notification mail

Tags: emails, files, entities

I have an Entity form with a file upload and need to include multiple filenames in the mail that is sent to the site admin upon form submission.

If I only allow *one* file to be uploaded through the form the replacement pattern [entity:field-uploadfield:file] works fine to make rules display the filename in the notification mail. But if I enable the users to upload multiple files the replacement pattern does not work anymore – how can I solve this?

**Edit**:
[entity:field-uppladdarfaltet:0:file] works, but then I'd have to cap the number of files at like 10 and also this doesn't really seem like a "clean" solution. Can I use the :0 :1 :2... format to support an unlimited amount of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[UPDATED]** Your Rule will need to have some additional actions preceding the Send Mail action.

1. ***Add variable (Text)***. Let's call it - `[file_list]`
2. ***Add Loop*** that loops over your file field `[entity:field-uppladdarfaltet]` and produces a List Item. Lets call the list item variable `[file_n]`
3. ***Add action Add Variable*** (text). Call it `[file_item]`
4. ***Add action Set a Data Value***. Data to change will be `[file_item]`. Value to set will be [file-n:file:name]
5. ***Add action Set a Data Value***. Data to change will be `[file_list]`. Value to set will be `[file-list:value][file-item:value]<br>`. This will add each uploaded file's name to the list with a line break after the name.
6. Print variable `[file_list:value]` in the email body.

Here's screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Alright I'll have a go at it and see if I can get it up and running.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I can't seem to be able to add a loop for [entity:field-uppladdarfaltet], did you mean like this? [http://i.imgur.com/QeLq5Id.png](http://i.imgur.com/QeLq5Id.png)

Comment: yes, but remove the double bracket - `[[entity:field-uppladdarfaltet]] => [entity:field-uppladdarfaltet]`

Comment: Did that, but it still says `Error: Data selector entity:field-uppladdarfaltet for parameter list is invalid.` I barely have anything to choose from in the list of data selectors, don't know if that is of importance? [http://i.imgur.com/nTs8d8X.png](http://i.imgur.com/nTs8d8X.png)

Comment: your rule does not see the file field. Add a condition "Entity has field" and select your file field to expose it to the rule

Comment: Alright that fixed the field problem, but the mail only outputs [file_list] so I'm still missing something... any idea? [http://i.imgur.com/wtupHOD.png](http://i.imgur.com/wtupHOD.png)

Comment: I can see `[file-list:value]` in replacement patterns, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: I updated the answer. Follow those steps now. Had to set another variable in order for the file names to be picked up and fix some value references. I provided an idea for the action at first, that really had to be expanded upon. Such things are not easy to describe precisely step by step without having a test application.

Comment: Awesome, will try the updated steps then. It's my first time working with rules so I really appreciate your help here.

Comment: So I've got the loop working – but not when I set the `[file_item]` to `[file-n:file:name]`, that gives no output at all. If I use some random string like "uploaded stuff" it at least outputs the correct number of values in relation to the number of files uploaded. So the final thing for me to figure out is why your solution doesn't output the filenames since it is able to loop through them a correct amount of times. I'll investigate further, if you have any pointers let me know. [http://i.imgur.com/B11VuBJ.png](http://i.imgur.com/B11VuBJ.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36834/discussion-between-oksana-c-and-lenny).